# Unable to edit, remove new users. Unable to add images in Media Library. Error: “You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."

Tags: wordpress

I'm encountering three problems with my wordpress site:

**1. Error: “You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."**
When I try to create a new page or a new post of any custom post type I get the message above.

**2. Unable to edit, remove or create new user.**
The created users username does not show up in the overview. The user gets ID no 0. Also cannot log in with the new username and password.

**3. I cannot upload any images to Media Library.**
When I upload an image it says, uploading and the stops at "Compression..."

I have tried searching for answers and tested many possible solutions with out luck:

- Install WP-DB Manager and repaired the tables.
- Deactivated/activated plugins
- Changed theme
- Made sure there's no brackets or anything missing from wp-config.php
- Tried manually delete corrupt users to see if things resets.
- Setting ID as primary key in wp-posts table.

Nothing works. I'm desperate.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

[IMAGE: Error message when uploading image to Media Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BvtL.png)

---

**UPDATE:**

I solved the problem. I just had to add Auto Increment to my primary keys in tables wp_posts and wp_postmeta. It worked. Now I can upload images to Media Gallery and add new pages/posts. BUT I can still not add new users. I get the following error message when clicking Save when creating a new user:

[IMAGE: Error message when creating new user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZpty.png)

Comment: what is image size?

Comment: I don't think the image size is the problem. It seems as if tried to upload the image to wp_posts with ID 0 which is occupied. I added a image to the original post.

Comment: are you migrate wordpress??

Comment: which version wordpress are you using?

Comment: I am not migrating wordpress. I am using the latest 4.7. I just solved problem 1 and 2 btw. Read my update.

Comment: @Anna, please post your update as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

I solved the problem. I just had to add Auto Increment to my primary keys in tables wp_posts and wp_postmeta. It worked. Now I can upload images to Media Gallery and add new pages/posts. BUT I can still not add new users.

Comment: You have to add Auto Increment to all tables. Some tables may no longer let you do that if there was no unique constraint on the ID, such as wp_options. In this case it won't do any harm because the option_id does not serve any purpose as far as I can tell, so you can ignore it. In other cases where there are duplicates you may have to repair the keys by hand by making them unique.

Comment: In my experience if database is locked. then you can't perform it well in posts and pages. You need to click the ‘Browse’ button next to the WordPress options tables (wp_options).
Select database and wp-options

This brings up all of the rows inside the options table. 

You need to find the row with the option name ‘core_updater.lock’ and click on the ‘Delete’ button next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too, when i did import database backup all primary keys and whole database structure became corrupted.
the problem was caused by a checked checkbox before importing backup file of the database.
problem solved by Uncheck "Do not use AUTO_INCREMENT for zero values" before upload the database backup.